# About removing repos

Tags: apt, software-installation, repository, official-repositories, add-apt-repository

[image]

- Is it safe to remove unselected repos?
- Is it safe to disable universe repo? or does ubuntu use it? cause apt-get update takes long time.
- Is it safe to remove duplicate repos? like spotify?

Comment: My questions are not about a specific ubuntu version, it's about ubuntu in general. althougt i'm trying xubuntu 14.04 on the pc where I took the screenshot.  but it's irrelevant, so it's not about ubuntu +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Depends. By default, when you add a repo (PPA or otherwise), two entries get created: one for the regular binary packages and one for the source code. For PPAs, the source code isn't directly downloadable through `apt-get`, so I personally have those entries disabled. For non-PPAs, it depends on the provider. You can remove these sources entries (labelled with "(Source Code)") without any major downside to the stability of the system; you just won't be able to download the sources as easily. You could also remove unchecked non-source entries, since `apt-get` and other frontends effectively consider those as non-existant.
2. Don't disable the universe repo unless you have a very good reason. While the default Ubuntu installation doesn't use anything from this repo (to the best of my knowledge), there are tons of software in this repo that you can easily install (as compared to downloading from the website). There's a good chance that you are using software from this repo, and disabling this repo would disable updates to the programs you are using. For example, the Chromium browser and KDE packages are in the universe repo. The XFCE terminal (which should be included in Xubuntu) is in the universe repo.
3. The Spotify example you listed isn't exactly a duplicate entry (one is for the binary packages and the other is for the source packages), but there are source code duplicates for the webupd8team/java PPA that you can (and should) remove.

Comment: so i could safely remove the fist 3 repos right?

Comment: First three as in the two cdrom's and the Canonical Partners or something else?

Comment: yes, aren't those none source repo and therefore safe to remove?

Comment: The cdrom entries are safe to remove, and the Canonical Partner entries can be removed (there are two in the list). However, I would personally keep that entry in the list in case there is some closed-source software you want to install later (Skype comes to mind, although they also offer a deb on their website).

Comment: Note that even just unchecking the entry (disabling the entry) prevents `apt` from getting updates from that source.

Comment: so you'd only remove the java repos?

Comment: I would remove the duplicate Java (source code) entries, the duplicate Canonical Partners (both binary and source code), one of the Spotify (source code) entries, and the cdrom entries. Any other unchecked or source code entries are up to you.